# replace current string from textfile database

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

From textfile database format,

> Customer:HDB:Price:Left:Available
>
> Ted:rm4:34:197:101

bash shell script,

```
read -p $'Price: '  Price2
sed -i "s/$Customer:$HDB:$Price/$Customer:$HDB:$Price2/g" CustomerDB.txt
```

When I key in 43, database return

> Ted:rm4:4334:197:101

How do i replace it to be 43 instead of 34?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `$Price` is empty. Are you sure it contains the old price? If you want to replace all the prices regardless of the old value, you can use

```
sed -i "s/$Customer:$HDB:[0-9]*/$Customer:$HDB:$Price2/g" CustomerDB.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I'd use awk rather than sed as it parses the line into seperate fields automaitcally.

```
read -p "customer: " cust
read -p "new price: " price2

awk -F : -v OFS=: -v cust=$cust -v price=$price2  '{ if($1==cust){ $3=price } ; print}' file
```

so what's happening?

Well the -F : sets the : as the field seperator
-v var=val sets some variables to use in the awk script in this case the OFS and the cust and price variables

the actuall awk script compares the first field ($1) with cust var. if they are the same it sets the 3rd field to be equal to the price var.

then we print out all the fields seperated by the value of OFS var ( space by default but we've overwritten to :'s)

[here's a good awk intro](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)